# How to filter dumped logcat file?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I have a logcat txt file received from a user. I would like to filter it by application, tags, etc. Ideally, to work with it as on live device.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Write code is not an easy way. There are online services, which allow to filter text lines https://www.gillmeister-software.com/online-tools/text/filter-and-remove-lines.aspx